# Navigation property is null when using fetchEntityByKey method in breeze

Tags: breeze

How can I also fetch navigation property of an entity while using fetchEntityByKey method in breeze ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "fetch" the value of a navigation property use the [EntityAspect.loadNavigationPrperty method](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html#method_loadNavigationProperty)

```
 myEntity.entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty("Orders").then(function (data) {
    var orders = data.results;
 }).fail(function (exception) {
    // handle exception here;
 });
```

Comment: In short, is .expand("Orders") better or myEntity.entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty ?

Comment: If you know the navigation properties that you need ahead of time when you are first querying then use "expand".  If you have already queried and realize that for just one entity that you need an additional relation then use "loadNavigationProperty"

Comment: To load multiple navigation properties, we need to call loadNavigationProperty multiple times ? In .expand, we can provide comma separated navigation property names.

Comment: The reason for the difference is that we want the promise callback function to always return a collection of entities that are all of the same type.  This occurs on a query because the 'expand' only affects nested properties of the returned entities.  We would break this rule if the loadNavigationProperty returned an array  containing multiple different types of entities. That said, it's not that difficult to create your own function to create this behavior.